# Matching fingerprint with a database SourceAFIS

Tags: c#, .net, fingerprint

I've create a very simple program in C# that will match a fingerprint with a database that contains multiple fingerprints. I'm using SourceAFIS to do that.
This is the source code of that:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using SourceAFIS.Simple;

namespace FingerprintRecognizer
{
    class Class1
    {
        static AfisEngine AFIS = new AfisEngine();
        static Person DatabasePersons = new Person();
        static Person CandidatePerson = new Person();
        static Fingerprint DatabaseFingerprints = new Fingerprint();
        static Fingerprint CanditateFingerprint = new Fingerprint();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Populating database with previously saved fingerprints of many people.
            foreach (string DatabaseTIFfiles in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\database\", "*.tif"))
            {
                DatabaseFingerprints.AsBitmap = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(DatabaseTIFfiles));
                DatabasePersons.Fingerprints.Add(DatabaseFingerprints);
            }

            // Inserting candidate fingerprint in another database.
            CanditateFingerprint.AsBitmap = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\testfingerprint.tif"));
            CandidatePerson.Fingerprints.Add(CanditateFingerprint);

            // Extracting skeletons of database fingerprints and candidate fingerprint.
            AFIS.Extract(DatabasePersons);
            AFIS.Extract(CandidatePerson);

            // Matching
            float score = AFIS.Verify(DatabasePersons, CandidatePerson);
            bool match = (score > 80);
            int points = Convert.ToInt32(score);

            if (match)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Fingerprint match with {0} points", points.ToString()));
            else
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Fingerprint does not match with {0} points", points.ToString()));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I'll obtaing two possible results:
"Fingerprint match with {0} points" or "Fingerprint does not match with {0} points"

If is it possible I want obtain a result like that: "Fingerprint match with "Name Surname".

I've tryed to follow this but I don't understand how to do that.  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SourceAFIS/Tutorial

Comment: `DatabasePersons.Fingerprints.Add(DatabaseFingerprints);` - as `DatabasePersons` is an instance of `Person`, aren't you adding all the fingerprints in your database to one person? The docs say _"In order to search whole database of fingerprints, **put all Person objects** (candidates) into a collection and pass this collection to AfisEngine.Identify along with probe Person to look up"_

Comment: Solved using a List. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Marco, could you post the example of the List you used please? Looking to do the exact same thing. Thanks